# Can I use "needs" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> "Richard needs some modification of the interface".

The use of **'needs'** is correct here? or I have to use **'need'**?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "needs" because it is [how you conjugate "need"](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/need) in singular third person (he/she/it).